# NGINX listen websocket client's call

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, passenger, reverse-proxy

I have a simple nodejs on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine.
How can I configure nginx or passenger to listen calls to ws://localhost:8443/helloworld, even if the client is on localhost:3000?

*server.js* looks like:

```
var path = require('path');
var ws = require('ws');
var express = require('express');
var minimist = require('minimist');
var url = require('url');
var fs    = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));

/* ======================================== */
/* =======                         ======== */
/* =======    WEBSOCKETS SERVER    ======== */
/* =======                         ======== */
/* ======================================== */

var asUrl = url.parse("http://localhost:8443/");
var port = asUrl.port;
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port, function() {
    console.log('********** WS HTTP SERVER STARTED********** ');
});

var wss = new ws.Server({
    server : server,
    path : '/helloworld'
});

/* ======================================== */
/* =========    WSS ON CONNETION   ======== */
/* ======================================== */
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {

    console.log('**** CONNECTION RECEIVED =D');
    ws.send(JSON.stringify("WELCOME FROM SERVER =D"));

    ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
        console.log('********** RECEIVED MSG '+data);
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});
/* ======================================== */
```

In my *static/index.html* file I have:

```
<!-- ======================================= -->
<!-- ==========       CSS        =========== -->
<!-- ======================================= -->
  <style>
    p { line-height:18px; }
    div { width:500px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
    #content { padding:5px; background:#ddd; border-radius:5px; 
               overflow-y: scroll; border:1px solid #CCC;margin-top:10px; height: 160px; }
    #input_hello { border-radius:2px; border:1px solid #ccc; margin:10px; padding:5px; width:50%; float:left;}
    #status { width:88px;display:block;float:left;margin-top:15px; }
  </style>


<!-- ======================================= -->
<!-- ========== JS FOR WEBSOCKET =========== -->
<!-- ======================================= -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //-- ======================================= --//

            // ======================== //
            // ====== CONNECTION ====== //
            // ======================== //

            var content = $('#content');
            var message = $('#input_hello input[type="text"]').val();
            var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8443/helloworld');

            ws.onopen = function() {
                alert("YOU ARE CONNECTED WITH WSS!!!!");
            };

            // ======================== //
            // ====== ON KEY PRESS ==== //
            // ======================== //

            $("#input_hello").keydown(function(event) {
              // ======= IF IS ENTER ===== //
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                  ws.send(message);
                  return false;
                 }
              // ======================== //
            });

            // ======================== //
            // ====== WS MESSAGE ====== //
            // ======================== //
            ws.onmessage = function(msg) {
                alert("RECEIVED MESSAGE WITH WSS!!!!");
                addMessage(msg.data);
            }

            // ======================== //
            // ==== RENDER MESSAGE ==== //
            // ======================== //
            function addMessage(message) {
                content.prepend('<p><span>' + message + '</span></p>');
                $("#input_hello").val("");
            }
    //-- ======================================= --//
    });
</script>





<!-- ======================================== -->
<!-- ======================================== -->
<!-- ========           HTML          ======= -->
<!-- ======================================== -->
<!-- ======================================== -->
<h1>HELLO FROM EXPRESS</h1>
<div id="content"></div>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="input_hello" />
</div>
<!-- ======================================== -->
```

This is my *etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default* file:

```
#===================#
#==== SERVER::80 ===#
#===================#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        #========================#
        #====    FOR ROOT   =====#
        #========================#
            root /home/deploy/Desktop/NODE_APP/static;
        #========================#
        #==== FOR PASSENGER =====#
        #========================#
            passenger_enabled on;
            passenger_app_env development;
            passenger_app_type node;
            passenger_app_root /home/deploy/Desktop/NODE_APP;
            passenger_startup_file /home/deploy/Desktop/NODE_APP/server.js;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}

#===================#
#=== SERVER 8443 ===#
#===================#
server {
        listen 8443;
        listen [::]:8443;

        #========================#
        #====    FOR ROOT   =====#
        #========================#
            root /nowhere; #========== NO NEED STATIC FILES..(ONLY WS!)
        #========================#
        #==== FOR WEBSOCKETS ====#
        #========================#
        location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_pass http://localhost:8443/helloworld;
        }
}

#=======================================#
#=======================================#
```

When I run `node /home/deploy/Desktop/NODE_APP/server.js`, I can access localhost:3000 or localhost:8443 and connect with the node.js server running on 8443 by websockets on ws://localhost:8443/helloworld.

But when I run `sudo service nginx start`, I can't exchange anymore websockets with node.js server running on 8443 by ws://localhost:8443/helloworld

How can I configure nginx or passenger to listen calls to
ws://localhost:8443/helloworld, even if the client is on localhost:3000?

Comment: Is your express app only serving requests over the websocket or is it also handling some on the port 80 server? It looks like this could be simplified a bit but I wanted to check.

Comment: Thank you @CamdenNarzt for the answer. Im gonna write in cap so anyone can see: I HAVE ONE MAIN SERVER RUNNING ON PORT 3000. AND IM USING THIS EXPRESS SERVER AS A STANDALONE JUST FOR STATIC FILES, RUNNING ON PORT 8443(AS HTTP) AND HERE I CREATE A WS CONNECTION LISTENING ON 8443/helloworld.

Comment: How can i configure NGINX, to listen this second server on port 8443/helloworld, JUST FOR THE WS DATA, NOT FOR RENDER ANY HTML PAGE ETC.. I WANNA KEEP ON THE MAIN SERVER VIEW.

Comment: PLEASE, JUST A SUGGEST, I THINK THE BEST WAY TO HELP EVERYONE IS A SOLUTION THAT WORKS BOTH IF IS A HTTP or HTTPS connection. JUST DEPENDING ON THE USER THE CONFIGS NECESSARIES IF HE PREFER ON SSL. BUT THE NGINX PROXY COULD BE ABSTRACT!

Comment: The problemas is that i keep receiving EADDRINUSE 8443, Address already in use. But i cant relie on Cluster or pm2 to solve this. I think is about the NGINX PROXY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have your app and nginx listen on the same port. You'll need your app to listen for websocket connections on another port, and have nginx forward from 8443 to that port.

Also if you are using multiple ports in your app, you need to tell Passenger which one is the "main" one: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/nodejs/reverse_port_binding.html#caveat-multiple-http-server-objects-error-http-server-listen-was-called-more-than-once

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much @CamdenNarzt !! Do you have an example in mind to share?